# Different definitions of Banach lattices?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-lattices

Do I get it correctly, that the are different definitions of "Banach lattices" available in the literature? To be precise, some authors (like [Schaefer](http://books.google.de/books?id=GQ-oAAAAIAAJ)) include the order continuity of the norm, while others do not (like [Abramovich Aliprantis](http://books.google.de/books?id=5h8bEWNalwMC))?

Comment: norm of $\ell_\infty$ is not order continuous. It is strange not see $\ell_\infty$ among Banach lattices because it is classical $M$-space

Comment: I found my error. I meant, the definition includes (vs. does not include) $|x| \le |y|$ implies $\|x\| \le \|y\|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After small discussion in comments it turns out that you use wrong definition of order-continuity. The standard one is
$$
\inf A=0\implies\inf_{u\in A}\Vert u\Vert=0
$$
for each non-empty downwards directed subset $A$ of Banach lattice $X$.

The property you stated in the comment is the definition of Riesz norm. For details see [Measure Theory. Vol 3. section 354 by D. H. Fremlin](http://www.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt.htm).

Comment: Thank you for answering the question I stated ;) What is above the question I *meant* to state? Is a Banach lattice (usually?) defined to have a Riesz norm?

Comment: By definition Banach lattice is a complete normed lattice with Reisz norm

Comment: I checked again my books and found the bad guy causing confusion: Troianiello (Elliptic differential equations and obstacle problems) uses $\|u^+\| \le \| u\|$ in his definition of Banach lattices. This renders the Sobolev space $H^1$ a Banach lattice. Using the usual definition, $H^1$ is indeed *not* a Banach lattice.